# gnus-dired-attach <return> based keybinding does not work

Tags: key-bindings

I am on gnu emacs 26.3 linux mint 20.1 and since my last OS update I cannot attach multiple files via dired using the key-binding `C-c RET C-a`. The message buffer indicates that `C-c <return> C-a is undefined`. Strangely, the supposedly equivalent `C-c C-m C-a` does work. Is there any way to debug what is happening? To be clear, I have a message and dired buffers open, I mark some files on dired, and hit `C-c RET C-a`, but the files do not get attached to the message buffer.

Comment: `C-m` is the same as `RET`, but it is not necessarily the same as `<return>`. A guess is that `C-h k` followed by your hitting the Return key shows you `<return>`. You may have to explicitly add a key binding for that `<return>` function key in the given mode map.

Comment: If you discover that the problem is in fact a difference between `<return>` and `RET` (aka `C-m`), then consider changing your question title to speak of `<return>` or "the Return key", and not of `RET`.

Comment: Output from `C-h k` + Return key is: RET (translated from <return>) runs the command dired-find-file (found in dired-mode-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘dired.el’. It is bound to RET, e..f, <menu-bar> <immediate> <find-file>.

Comment: which means that `RET` and `<return>` are the same right?

Comment: They're not the same (logical) key. What it means is that Emacs sees function key `<return>` when you hit the Return physical key, but since `<return>` has no key binding Emacs translates to `RET` and uses the binding for `RET`. Perhaps (dunno) such translation doesn't happen when `RET` is used as a prefix key, as in your example: `C-c RET C-a`. Perhaps (dunno) you need to add a specific binding for that, and define `C-c <return>` as a prefix key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...this solution works. The question still lingers though, over why this happened in the first place. Thank you @Drew

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <return> C-a") 'gnus-dired-attach)
```